# Woocommerce : sort product category page by both year (not date) and sku

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, sku

I'm trying to sort the products of a specific category page by descending year (not the full date, only the year) then by ascending *SKUs*.

The idea is to group product by year and, inside of this group, to sort them by *sku*.

I’ve found a way to target a specific category, and a code that orders products by ascending *SKUs*. Since i’m new to php i’m still struggling to find out how to sort by year (again, not the full date) and how to « chain » those two codes (order by year, then by SKUs).

Here's the bit of code i'm using :

```
if( is_product_category('19')) {
        
    $args['meta_key'] = '_sku';
    $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
    $args['order'] = ‘ASC’; 
    return $args;
}
```

I’ve also found documentation (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters) with an exemple that orders by title and menu_order with different sort order, but i don’t know how to integrate this in the previous code

```
$args = array( 'orderby' => array( 'title' => 'DESC', 'menu_order' => 'ASC' ) );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks for reading me !

Julien

**UPDATE**

I was trying to solve my issue and i’ve found a way around, that isn’t 100% satisfying but stil works. I understood how to chain two different order set with different sort order but I still don’t know how to order by year.

As a way-around, i used the « menu order » field and, in every product page, i manually filled it with the year.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'test_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');
function test_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $args ) {
    
    if( is_product_category('19')) {
        
    $args['meta_key'] = '_sku';
    $args['orderby']  = ['menu_order' => 'DESC', 'meta_value' => 'ASC'];
    return $args;
    } }
```

It sorts my products by menu_order field (descending) first, then it sort all products with the same ‘menu_order’ by ascending sku.

It does exactly what i was looking for but It’s a bit tedious to manually fill every product’s menu_order so i’m still open for a better solution !

thanks again

Comment: You can try with raw query. Could you please share your details code?

Comment: @MainulHasan I just updated my question with more details and a solution i've found (but it's not perfect)

Answer (score 1):

This should fix your problem. Add following function in your functions.php active parent/child theme.

```
function filter_products_by_year_sku( $q ) {
    if(!is_product_category( 'shirts' )) return; // Run this only if we are on shirts category
        $query = $q->get('query');
        $meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query' );
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'       => '_sku',
        );
        $q->set( 'year', date('Y') );
        $q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query);
        $q->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value date' );
        $q->set( 'order', 'DESC' ); // by default is ASC so comment if you want ASC.
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'filter_products_by_year_sku' );
```